# Can't get the values out side the for loop

Tags: java

out side the for loop i can't get all the values i am getting only last value the code is like below

```
public static void getHTMLElements(List<String> urls) throws IOException {

            getElements(urls);
            for (Map.Entry<String, HtmlElements> entry1 : urlList.entrySet()) {
                HtmlElements htmlele = entry1.getValue();
                System.out.println("url is " + entry1.getKey());
                System.out.println("Element Name is " + htmlele.getElementName());
                System.out.println("Attributes are " + htmlele.getAttributes());
            }

        }

        public static void getElements(List<String> urls) throws IOException {

            try {

                for (int i = 0; i < urls.size(); i++) {

                    String s = urls.get(i);

                    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(s).get();

                    getInputElements(doc, s);

                }
            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        public static void getInputElements(Document doc, String urls) {
            // List l=new ArrayList();
            HtmlElements htmlElements = new HtmlElements();
            Properties attributes = new Properties();

            Elements elements = doc.getAllElements();
            for (Element element : elements) {
                if (!element.tagName().contains("script")) {
                    String elementName = element.tagName();
                    Attributes attr = element.attributes();
                    for (Attribute attr1 : attr) {

                        if (attr1.getKey().contains("id")) {
                            attributes.put(attr1.getKey(), attr1.getValue());

                        }
                        if (attr1.getKey().contains("name")) {
                            attributes.put(attr1.getKey(), attr1.getValue());
                        }
                        if (attr1.getKey().contains("type")) {
                            attributes.put(attr1.getKey(), attr1.getValue());
                        }
                    }
                    htmlElements.setElementName(elementName);
                    htmlElements.setAttributes(attributes);

                }
                urlList.put(urls, htmlElements);

            }
    }
    }
```

In the above code i am trying to get all the lelements from the website url.But,elementName i can't get properly.getting only last value.i want to get values outside the for loop.

Comment: The value gets _overwritten_ as the loop _loops_.  As such, you see the last value outside the _loop_.

Comment: when you set a variable with a value, it replaces the value. Try moving your print statement into the loop.

Comment: What is it that you want to do?

Comment: Did you mean String[] elementNames?
I don't understand what your problem is.

Comment: Define the meaning of "proper value of elementName".

Comment: Please check my complete code.i want to get those values out side the for loop

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want the elementName contain the name of the element that has "script". In that case when you found the element you need to stop looping. Add break into your if statement
            `if (!element.tagName().contains("script")) {
                elementName = element.tagName();
                break;
            }`

Answer (score 0):

Since `String elementName` assigned only the last value in for loop. If you need all `tagName`, declare `List<String> tagNames = new ArrayList<String>();` collection and

```
 if (!element.tagName().contains("script")) {
    tagNames.add(element.tagName());
 }
```

This way you have all tag names in the list.

Comment: Thanks,It's working.But,if you see my above code how can i get the attribute values from out side the for loop.

Comment: Can you specify `HtmlElements` class? I know `HtmlElement` but not `HtmlElements` class